# How to Solve OrderBy in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I have this problem with Cassandra to use ORDER by

this is my query

```
public static final Select GET_USERS = QueryBuilder.select().all().from("user");
```

But When I use Order By Have a problem with this

```
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: ORDER BY is only supported when the partition key is restricted by an EQ or an IN.
```

Could you please help me how to use order by on my query?

Comment: https://docs.datastax.com/en/404.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a partition key to query using order by clause. Below SO post has details on how ORDER BY clause work in Cassandra. Hopefully, that will help you clarify

[Where and Order By Clauses in Cassandra CQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35708118/where-and-order-by-clauses-in-cassandra-cql)