# CQL query returns InvalidRequest error "ORDER BY is only supported when the partition key is restricted by an EQ or an IN."

Tags: cassandra

I'm trying to use the ORDER BY command in Cassandra Query Language (CQL) to sort my data by a specific column in my table, but I keep getting an "InvalidRequest" error message.

Here's the table definition I used:

```
CREATE TABLE monthly_earnings (
  id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
  year INT,
  month INT,
  total_revenue_cents INT,
  num_subscribers INT
);
```

Then I populated it with some data:
[image]

And here's the query I tried to run:

```
SELECT * FROM monthly_earnings WHERE year = 2020 ORDER BY total_revenue_cents ASC;
```

However, when I ran this query, I got the following error message:

```
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="ORDER BY is only supported when the partition key is restricted by an EQ or an IN."
```

I also tried to run:

```
SELECT * FROM monthly_earnings WHERE year = 2020 ORDER BY total_revenue_cents ASC;
```

and got this error:

```
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering and thus may have unpredictable performance. If you want to execute this query despite the performance unpredictability, use ALLOW FILTERING"
```

I also tried to run the query with the `ALLOW FILTERING` option:

```
SELECT * FROM monthly_earnings WHERE year = 2020 ORDER BY total_revenue_cents ASC ALLOW FILTERING;
```

But it didn't work either:

```
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="ORDER BY is only supported when the partition key is restricted by an EQ or an IN."
```

So, I created an index on the total_revenue_cents column:

```
CREATE INDEX total_revenue_cents_idx ON monthly_earnings (total_revenue_cents);
```

And then ran this:

```
SELECT * FROM monthly_earnings WHERE year = 2020 ORDER BY total_revenue_cents ASC ALLOW FILTERING;
```

But when I ran the query again, I still received the same error message.

```
cqlsh:audio_streaming> SELECT * FROM monthly_earnings WHERE year = 2020 ORDER BY total_revenue_cents ASC ALLOW FILTERING;

InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="ORDER BY is only supported when the partition key is restricted by an EQ or an IN."
```

So, I've tried creating several tables with different partition keys, but I keep getting the same error. I'm stumped as to why I'm encountering this error and how I can fix it. Can anyone provide some guidance? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is still relevant:
[Where and Order By Clauses in Cassandra CQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35708118/where-and-order-by-clauses-in-cassandra-cql)

In your case, to do the first query:

```
SELECT * FROM monthly_earnings 
WHERE year = 2020 
ORDER BY total_revenue_cents ASC;
```

This is what the table should look like:

```
CREATE TABLE monthly_earnings_by_year (
  year   INT,      
  month  INT,
  total_revenue_cents INT,
  num_subscribers INT,
  PRIMARY KEY((year), total_revenue_cents, month) 
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (total_revenue_cents ASC);
```

**Rational**:

- You need to request for a year => it is your partition key
- You need to sort by total_revenue_cents => it is in your key as a clustering columns
- You do not need extra `uuid` as couple year/month will likely ensure unicity
- You actually do not need the `ORDER BY` clause as `ASC` is the default ordering

Answer (score 1):

Your queries are not valid CQL statements for two reasons:

1. You cannot filter by `year` column because it is not part of the PRIMARY KEY.
2. You cannot sort the partitions into any order because partitions are distributed randomly across all nodes in the cluster.

As this error indicates:

```
... ORDER BY is only supported when the partition key is restricted by an EQ or an IN.
```

You have to filter by partition meaning the `WHERE` clause must specify either `pk = ?` or `pk IN(...)` because only rows WITHIN a partition can be sorted.

Another way of saying it is that your query is attempting to sort ALL records which isn't valid because it requires a full table scan which doesn't scale. Imagine if you had billions and billions of partitions across hundreds of nodes -- the query will never complete so it is not allowed.

The answer to the question you didn't ask is that you need to design a table for each application query. If your app needs to retrieve the earnings for a given year, you need to model the data like:

```
CREATE TABLE earnings_by_year (
    year int,
    total_revenue_cents int,
    month int,
    num_subscribers int,
    PRIMARY KEY(year, total_revenue_cents)
)
```

The `earnings_by_year` table (as the name suggests) is partitioned by `year` with rows clustered by `total_revenue_cents`. With this data model, you can query the table with:

```
SELECT * FROM earnings_by_year WHERE year = 2020
```

Note that it is not necessary to use the `ORDER BY` clause because by default the rows within partitions will already be sorted by the `total_revenue_cents` in ascending order. Cheers!